# How do I change the game object on a button click?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a five game objects (`ornament1`, `ornament2`, `ornament3`, `ornament4` and `ornament5`) and  two buttons (*"Next"* and *"Previous"*). When I click *"Next"*, the object should change from `ornament1` to `ornament2`. When I click *"Next"*, again, it should change from `ornament2`to `ornament3`; when I then click *"Previous"* it should change from `ornament3`to `ornament2`.

I have the *"Next"* button working, but the *"Previous"* button is not working. How do I change the game object on a button click?

---

Here is my code:

```
if(GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 20, 80, 50), "Ornament1"))
{
    Debug.Log("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh" + countbool);

    if(count==0)
    {
        Debug.Log("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh");
        ornament1.transform.position = new Vector3(-0.1428955f, -0.1894745f, 4.108555f);
        ornament1.SetActive(true);
        ornament2.SetActive(false);
        ornament3.SetActive(false);
        ornament4.SetActive(false);
        ornament5.SetActive(false);
        count++;
    }
    else if(count == 1)
    {
        ornament2.transform.position = new Vector3(-0.1428955f, -0.1894745f, 4.108555f);
        ornament2.SetActive(true);
        ornament1.SetActive(false);
        ornament3.SetActive(false);
        ornament4.SetActive(false);
        ornament5.SetActive(false);
        count++;
    }
    else if(count == 2)
    {   
        ornament3.transform.position = new Vector3(-0.1428955f, -0.1894745f, 4.108555f);
        ornament3.SetActive(true);
        ornament1.SetActive(false);
        ornament2.SetActive(false);
        ornament4.SetActive(false);
        ornament5.SetActive(false);
        count++;
    }
    else if(count == 3)
    {
        ornament4.transform.position = new Vector3(-0.1428955f, -0.1894745f, 4.108555f);
        ornament4.SetActive(true);
        ornament3.SetActive(false);
        ornament1.SetActive(false);
        ornament2.SetActive(false);
        ornament5.SetActive(false);
        count++;
    }
    else if(count == 4)
    {
        //ornament1.SetActive(true);
        ornament5.transform.position = new Vector3(-0.1428955f, -0.1894745f, 4.108555f);
        ornament5.SetActive(true);
        ornament3.SetActive(false);
        ornament1.SetActive(false);
        ornament2.SetActive(false);
        ornament4.SetActive(false);
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try and make all of them IF statements, not ELSE IF.

Comment: in previous button do you use count-- instead of count++

Comment: after giving count-- still its not working

Answer (score 2):

We know that your *"Next"* button works; at least, *mostly*. As such, we simply need to expand on your base code. That said, there are a few changes I make:

- I move all game objects into an array. Given the nature in which you are using them, this makes more logical sense. We can also directly access them using an integer index, where we could not, if we simply included the number in the actual name.
- I change the name of `count` to `currentOrnamentID`, as this value appears to point to the current game object, which does not really make sense as a "count".
- I store `originPosition` as a class member. That way, if you ever need to change this position, you change it once. Furthermore, I believe it might be a little lighter on the garbage collecting, by passing values into an already-existing `Vector3` instead of creating a new one.
- In your last `if` statement, that is, where `count == 4`, you still increment `count`. In such cases, you can end up with logic errors, as you are effectively moving on to a game object that does not exist (remember, you say that you only have 5 game objects). I have adjusted the logic to overlap; selecting *"Next"* on the last game object will return you to the first game object.
- You were previously resetting the `SetActive` for every game object, with each selection. This is unnecessary, as we should know what the last game object was. We only need to set the previous game object to `SetActive(false)`.

---

As such, you can see the logic, below. All you need to do is call `Next()` from the *"Next"* button, and `Previous()` from the *"Previous"* button. We then take the `currentOrnamentID`, and use it to determine what game object is currently displayed. We adjust this value, accordingly, before we send the new `currentOrnmanetID` and the previous `currentOrnamentID` by *value* to a `EnableOrnament` method. You will notice we pass a lot of direct values in; this is just a semantic difference in efficiency. We already know the exact values that should be passed, both to the new `currentOrnamentID` and `EnableOrnament`, given the specific context. No need to "work it out" again, by calling to the actual variables or performing `++`.

```
int currentOrnamentID = 0;
public GameObject[] ornaments;
public Vector3 originPosition = new Vector3(-0.1428955f, -0.1894745f, 4.108555f);

private void Next
{
    switch(currentOrnamentID)
    {
        case 0:
            currentOrnamentID = 1;
            EnableOrnament(1, 0);
            break;
        case 1:
            currentOrnamentID = 2;
            EnableOrnament(2, 1);
            break;
        case 2:
            currentOrnamentID = 3;
            EnableOrnament(3, 2);
            break;
        case 3:
            currentOrnamentID = 4;
            EnableOrnament(4, 3);
            break;
        case 4:
            currentOrnamentID = 0;
            EnableOrnament(0, 4);
            break;
    }
}

private void Previous
{
    switch(currentOrnamentID)
    {
        case 0:
            currentOrnamentID = 4;
            EnableOrnament(4, 0);
            break;
        case 1:
            currentOrnamentID = 0;
            EnableOrnament(0, 1);
            break;
        case 2:
            currentOrnamentID = 1;
            EnableOrnament(1, 2);
            break;
        case 3:
            currentOrnamentID = 2;
            EnableOrnament(2, 3);
            break;
        case 4:
            currentOrnamentID = 3;
            EnableOrnament(3, 4);
            break;
    }
}

private void EnableOrnament(int newID, int previousID)
{
    ornaments[previousID].SetActive(false);
    ornaments[newID].SetActive(true);

    ornaments[newID].transform.position = originPosition;
}
```